# CSS overflow:scroll causing an extra line break at the top of the text

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm trying to create a `div` section with an image and text inside it, with scrolling overflow, but when I add the `overflow: scroll`, an extra line break is added at the top of the text, and I can't figure out how to get rid of it.

I know it isn't the padding or margin that's the problem, because the image is still positioned at the top. The text just has extra space. And removing just the `overflow: scroll` line gets rid of it, so I can't figure out why it's happening.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
.scroll {
    height: 160px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

img.avatar {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 0px 6px 1px 0px;
    float: left;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="scroll">
            <img class="avatar" src="(link here)"><p>text here</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: post ur code pls...

Comment: Please post minimal code to recreate the issue

Comment: This should help you put enough code into your questio for us to be able to help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example In particular, how have you positioned the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed the margin of the `p` tag which is the problem here.

You may reproduce the behaviour you mentioned on other ways, e.g., using a `border` around the `.scroll` container.
The margin of the `p` tag is measured against the next element (in a minimal example, to the top of the page). If you set up a border or scrollbars, the margin is instead measured against the container itself, so it moves down.

To prohibit that behaviour, you could, for example, set a margin of 0 to the `p` tag.